# Networking between openvpn and pptp clients

Tags: freebsd, openvpn, pptpd

Long uptime to everyone!

OS FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE, pptpd-1.3.4.

Network:

```
em0 1.2.3.4 - external interface and ip
tun0 10.18.1.0/24 - network for openvpn clients
tun1 10.18.2.0/24 - network for pptp clients
```

Configuration.

/etc/ppp.conf:

```
default:
 set timeout 0
 set log Phase Chat LCP IPCP CCP TUN Command Connect
 disable vjcomp deflate pred1

pptp:
 set device localhost:pptp
 set ifaddr 10.18.2.101 10.18.2.102-10.18.2.113 255.255.255.0
 set server /tmp/loop "" 0177
 enable chap
 enable MSChapV2
 disable pap
 disable ipv6cp
 enable proxy
 allow mode direct
```

/usr/local/etc/pptpd.conf:

```
logwtmp
debug
noipparam
delegate
proxyarp
+MSChap-V2 mppe-128 mppe-stateless
pidfile /var/run/pptpd.pid
```

/etc/pf.conf:

```
table <sshguard> persist
block in quick on em0 proto tcp from <sshguard> to any port 22 label "ssh bruteforce"

pass quick on lo0 all
pass quick on em0 all
```

/etc/rc.conf:

```
gateway_enable="YES"
```

/etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.link.ether.inet.proxyall=1
```

Some warnings in log files:

```
tun1: Warning: Local: bind: Address already in use
tun1: Warning: set server: Failed 2
tun1: Warning: 10.18.2.112: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
tun1: Warning: 10.18.2.112: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP

tun2: Warning: Local: bind: Address already in use
tun2: Warning: set server: Failed 2
tun2: Warning: 10.18.2.104: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
```

Routes@openvpn client:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 ppp0
10.18.1.0       10.18.1.61      255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.18.1.61      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.18.2.0       10.18.1.61      255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
```

So, from openvpn client I can ping 10.18.2.101, but not pptp clients.
From server I can ping any pptp and openvpn clients including hosts in their internal networks.
Is it possible to complete the quest with proxyarp or I need to look for NAT ?

Comment: Rather than a massive config dump for us to sort through can you possibly describe your problem more clearly (What you are trying to do, the expected behavior, and what's actually happenning) and trim the configs to the most relevant bits (we can always ask for more if needed)?  It may be because it's almost 1:30 in the morning here, but this question just makes my head hurt.  Thanks :-)

Comment: Excuse me, forgot about my problem ;) PPTP and OpenVPN clients can't access each other.